# Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test for two-level dependent ordinal variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data, kruskal-wallis-test

Hello I've been reading multiple references regarding the use Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test for ordinal variables, but none explicitly mentioned or cautioned against using this to a dependent variable with only 2 levels (example: low and high - coded as 1 and 2)

Is it okay to use Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test for cases mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

The usual Kruskal-Wallis test assumes continuous response. As such, it is not 100% suitable for your situation. There are (at least) two options:

1. Use a simulation version of Kruskal-Wallis
2. Use a more common test of association between a grouping variable and a binary response like Fisher's exact test for general cross-tables or a simulation Chi-squared test.

Here an example in R

```
library(coin)

set.seed(1)

x <- factor(LETTERS[rep(1:4, each = 10)])
y <- sample(1:2, 40, TRUE)

# "Exact" options
fisher.test(table(y, x)) # p-value = 0.3913
chisq.test(table(y, x), simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1e5) # p-value = 0.392
kruskal_test(y ~ x, distribution = approximate(nresample = 1e5)) # p-value = 0.3917

# Classic KW test assumes continuous response
kruskal.test(y ~ x) # p-value = 0.3547
```

Comment: "The usual Kruskal-Wallis test assumes continuous response." In general, the KW test does not make any distributional assumptions at all. Do you mean that the usual implementations of Kruskal-Wallis test cannot deal with ties? I agree with the rest of your answer, of course!

Comment: Hello, from online resources, they mentioned that Kruskal-Wallis test can be used for both continuous and ordinal-level dependent variables. Is this wrong?

Comment: As long as you deal with ties, it is fine.

Comment: Yes it’s ties that’s the issue.  Best to use the proportional odds model which generalizes K-W and handles the most extreme form of ties in which Y is binary.  See https://fharrell.com/post/rpo